# Animate background when entering foreground

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am working on a stopwatch app that begins flashing when approaching limit and again when overtime. Everything works great except for when the app is pushed to the background and then brought to the foreground again. At that time the animation will not start.

I have tried moving the code to `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` but it produces a fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Am I missing something basic here?

There is more to the code of course (calculations, etc.), but this is relevant section. (Edit: I've expanded this to provide a better view of what I'm doing.)

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if timerOn == 0 {
        myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        timerOn = 1
        redOrYellow = "white"
        startButton.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: startButton)
        background.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: background)
        pickerMask.isHidden = false
    }
}
....

     func animateLight() {

    if redOrYellow == "red" {
        print("red")

        //background.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: background)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.01, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }, completion: nil)

    } else if redOrYellow == "yellow" {
        print("yellow")

        //background.superview?.sendSubview(toBack: background)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.1, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            self.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }, completion: nil)
    }
}

func updateCounter() {
    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
    totalTime = elapsedTime
    if totalTime >= partBaseTimes[numberOfSelectedPart] {
        if redOrYellow != "red" {
            redOrYellow = "red"
            animateLight()
        }
    } else if totalTime >= (partBaseTimes[numberOfSelectedPart] - 30) {
        if redOrYellow != "yellow" {
            redOrYellow = "yellow"
            animateLight()
        }
    }

    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)
    let fractionOfSecond = UInt8(elapsedTime * 10)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFractionOfSecond = String(format: "%01d", fractionOfSecond)
    talkTimer.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFractionOfSecond)"
    }
```

Comment: I don't think app enter background will cause animation to stop when it brought back to foreground. Your animation block should be in your view controller, not in app delegate.

Comment: @kientux Thanks. The animation block is in the ViewController, I am simply calling the function from App delegate so that it will fire upon returning to foreground.

Comment: Sorry I've just try that and really, the animation stops when app enter foreground again. You could try this in applicationWillResignActive: `[yourViewController.view.layer removeAllAnimations]`
and in applicationDidBecomeActive: `[yourViewController animate]`.

Comment: I tried `ViewController().view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` in applicationWillResignActive and it did not like it. And Xcode doesn't accept `animate`. I'm using xcode8 (beta 6) and Swift 3 if that's relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it did not like it"? `ViewController().view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` - you're initializing a new viewcontroller instead of using your existed one. You should create a UIViewController property of AppDelegate then assign it with your view controller. And `animate` is just my function, you must replace it with your `animateLight()`.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Still relatively new to this and I mix my syntax. However, this `myViewController.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()` in applicationWillResignActive gives me this `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. And I misread your`animate`, but with my function it gives the same `fatal error` as above.

Comment: How did you set your `myViewController` in AppDelegate?

Comment: `var myViewController: ViewController!'

Comment: yes but did you assign it to your actual view controller? Like this, from your view controller:
`UIApplication.shared.delegate.myViewController = self`

Comment: Well it seems that I've been improperly referencing vc in my apps. I'm glad you pointed that out. I need to take a day and figure out what I've been doing wrong. Thanks for your help tonight! ;-)